# How to display a child layout on clicking a ListView row without masking the other rows?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simpleadapter

I have generated a ListView using SimpleAdapter. I am trying to display a tablerow on clicking the listview row. I want the TableRow to be displayed everytime I click a ListView row. I have done the following coding, but the TableRow masks or occupies the space of one of the ListView row below it, and secondly the Tablerow gets displayed only for the first row and not for the other rows. I am posting my codes below. Kindly help me step by step.

tasks extends Fragment

```
   ListAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),val,R.layout.senttaskdata,new String[]{"rname","heading","desc","id","path","receiver","sender"},new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.hide1,R.id.hide2,R.id.hide3,R.id.hide4})
  {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        //some codes here
        return v;
    }

  };

 sent.setAdapter(k);

  sent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TableRow colors=(TableRow)arg0.findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
        RelativeLayout r=(RelativeLayout)arg0.findViewById(R.id.tasksent);
        r.setVisibility(arg0.VISIBLE);
        colors.setVisibility(arg0.VISIBLE);

    }
});
```

my xml file for get the values into the List i.e senttaskdata

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tasksent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mypicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/border" />


  <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
   android:visibility="invisible"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/dblue"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_status" />

 </TableRow>



 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use visiblity="GONE"** then your view is not rendered and doesn't take place in your layout but you can reference it.

Comment: I tried using that, but the row below it gets hidden i.e the Tablerow gets displayed over the Listview row

Comment: Your relative layout height property is set to match_parent try wrap_content

Comment: Whats the difference between match parent and wrap content?

Comment: If you have layout or control inside other element with width set to match_parent means that this element will have same width as its container, where wrap_content make sure that your control will have width set to minimal required value.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a relativeLayout, everything, including your new child must be laid out - relative to each other or the container they reside in.  Your new child gets displayed over the other rows because you didn't set the layout parameters.   Try using something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParms lp = new RelativeLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LayoutParms. layout_alignAbove, someView);
```

If you use a LinearLayout, then simply setting 
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" on the ListView layout solves all your problems automagically and children are hidden or exposed very cleanly and smoothly